# How do I share a Google Drive video on YouTube?

Tags: google-drive, youtube

I have lots of videos on Drive. How can I share a Google Drive video on YouTube, now that we no longer have an upload email address?

Answer (score 2):

I had to go into Google Photos and enable Google Drive, then I could upload the image from photos in the YouTube upload page.

[image: Google Photos settings]